# Fetch core data entity in list

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

The core data `User` I create with property `id and name`, which I want to fetch it into list.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: User.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var users: FetchedResults<User>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.id) { user in  // Type '_' has no member 'id'
                    // Text(user.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused with the error report seems it is not successfully import core data entity.

**UPDATE**

When I try to use the name property in list, it also report `Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'name'` error message.

```
ForEach(users, id: \.id) { user in
    Text(user.name)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At times, you need to build the project for the entity to be recognized in code. Here's the code for loading the CoreData entity User with id and name.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: User.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    var users: FetchedResults<User>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(users, id: \.id) { user in
                Text("Id = \(user.id), Name = \(user.name ?? "")")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make the User entity conform to Identifiable. Doing so, you can skip the id parameter in the ForEach.

```
extension User: Identifiable {
}

ForEach(users) { user in
    Text("Id = \(user.id), Name = \(user.name ?? "")")
}
```

[image: User entity setup]

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: The version 11.3.1.

Comment: I'm using the same version and I don't see any errors. Are you sure you created name and id attributes with appropriate types for the User entity? I've updated the answer with a screenshot of my entity.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this [article](https://dev.to/maeganwilson_/how-to-make-a-task-list-using-swiftui-and-core-data-513a), I create a new UserRow struct to hold the core data entity, and it works correctly for me. But I think there is some knowledge I have missing in this situation, it will be very kind if someone could explain for me.

```
// in MyView add the new struct

struct UserRow: View {
    var user: User

    var body: some View {
        Text(user.name ?? "No name given")
    }
}


// then replace the list with

List {
    ForEach(users) { user in
        UserRow(user: user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post this a new question. It this code works for you, what do you think you are missing?

Comment: I think about why we need to create a struct to reflect to core data entity, is it possible to use entity directly?

Comment: Which struct are you referring to? Where do you want to use entity directly?

Comment: The struct `var user: User` must be create to hold the `var users: FetchedResults<User>`.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question.